# UITableView header image download using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am using GCD to download the header image for the UITableView.

When I use `dispatch_async`, the image does not show up at all, and when I use `dispatch_sync`, it still a synchronous download. How do I fix this ?

```
eventDetailsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
eventDetailsTable.dataSource = self;
eventDetailsTable.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:eventDetailsTable];

NSString *headerImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [currentEvent objectForKey:@"baseurl"], [currentEvent objectForKey:@"sessionimage"]];
NSURL *headerImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:headerImageUrl];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:headerImageURL];
    UIImage *headerImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView *headerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:headerImage];
    eventDetailsTable.tableHeaderView = headerImageView;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update UI, you must do it on the main thread. So here is solution:

```
dispatch_async(global_queue, ^{
    //Do your work

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried that. It works in simulator, but it works on the device only 50% of the time